# Angular Directive with "restrict" and without "restrict"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I am confused with this directive definition object - (`restrict`).
I created two functions, first is with `restrict`, and the other one is without `restrict`.

As I run this code, both directives returned the same result.

**With** `restrict`:

```
app.directive 'helloWorld', ->
  return {

    restrict: 'AE'
    link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
       console.log "HELLO WORLD"

  }
```

**Without** `restrict`:

```
app.directive 'helloWorld', ->
  return {

    link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
       console.log "HELLO WORLD"

  }
```

Can somebody tell me what's going on here? 
PS: I am new in angular. Please, if you can help me with this it would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A directive can specify which of the 4 matching types it supports in the restrict property of the directive definition object.

`The default` is EA. i.e., if restrict isn't specified.

The restrict option is typically set to:

```
'A' - only matches attribute name
'E' - only matches element name
'C' - only matches class name
'M' - only matches the comment
```

These restrictions can all be combined as needed:

'AEC' - matches either attribute or element or class name
**or** 
(ECA - order doesn't matter)

[source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) - Angularjs docs

```
app.directive 'helloWorld', ->
  return 
     restrict: 'AE' 
     link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        console.log "HELLO WORLD"
```

and

```
app.directive 'helloWorld', ->
    return
       link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
          console.log "HELLO WORLD"
```

are same and has no difference. Both can be used as

```
<helloWorld> ... </helloWorld>
```

or

```
<ANY helloWorld> ... </ANY>
```

---

Say, If you have only `restrict E`. Then the directive functionalities applies only to

```
<helloWorld> ... </helloWorld>
```

and

```
<ANY helloWorld> ... </ANY> // wont work since the directive is bound only to element
```

Comment: "The default is EA. i.e., if restrict isn't specified." Thanks @Sibi Raj. its clear to me now.

Answer (score 2):

`Restrict` refers to the type of element that your directive should match, and does not affect (in any way) the return result of your directive. From the [angular docs:](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

```
'A' - only matches attribute name
'E' - only matches element name
'C' - only matches class name
'M' - only matches comment
```

These restrictions can all be combined as needed:

`'AEC' - matches either attribute or element or class name`

Comment: Just an addition: The reason why OP's directive is the same both with and without `restrict: 'AE'` is because, the default restriction for a directive is `'EA'`.

Answer (score 0):

just a little tip: if you name your directive in camelcase way, you need to replace it with `-` when using it in your html code, such as

```
<hello-world></hello-world>
```

when you set `E` value to your `restrict`  or

```
<ANY hello-world></ANY>
```

when you set `A` value.